# Parsing a large javascript object

Tags: javascript

I have this js object.  I'm trying to get to the legacy_publishers publisher_name

```
{"data":[{"title_id":7,"title":"Dead By Midnight","title_alpha":"Dead","display_title":"Dead By Midnight","subtitle":"","isbn10":"","isbn13":"9781420117554","primary_isbn13":"9781420117554","asin":"","format":"4","subformat":"1","publish_date":"2010-02-01","series_id":495,"series":{"series_id":495,"firebrand_series_id":null,"name":"Dead By","description":"dsfasdf","created":"2014-07-31T06:10:52.000-04:00","modified":null,"slug":"dead-by","legacy_slug":null},"volume":1,"pub_season":"","pub_year":"2010","bisac1":"FIC027110","bisac2":"","bisac3":"","major_category":"","minor_category":"","min_age":null,"max_age":null,"min_grade":null,"max_grade":null,"ean":"","barcode":"","dewey_decimal":"","lib_of_congress":"","spanish_language":0,"target_audience":0,"language":"","edition":"","pages":0,"number_in_series":0,"trimsize":"","filesize":"","duration_hours":0,"duration_minutes":0,"discs":0,"download":null,"size_unit":"","digitization_date":null,"us_on_sale_date":null,"aus_on_sale_date":null,"can_on_sale_date":null,"uk_on_sale_date":null,"us_list_price":"","aus_list_price":"","can_list_price":"","uk_list_price":"","isPrimary":"Y","modified":"2015-08-04T10:37:45.000-04:00","modifier":92,"activated":null,"active":"X","flagged_string":"","created":"2010-03-04T06:28:05.000-05:00","assets_id":"29012","book_details":null,"exclude_goodreads":"Y","series_description":"","review_quote1":"<p>&ldquo;Masterful!&rdquo; &mdash;<em>Linda Howard, New York Times bestselling author on Cold Hearted</em> - <i>Linda Howard</i></p><p>&ldquo;A powerful story that kept me up very late&mdash;with all the lights on.&rdquo; &mdash;<em>Kay Hooper, New York Times bestselling author on As Good as Dead</em> - <i>Kay Hooper</i></p>","territory_id":27,"featured_newsletter_id":0,"retailer_discovery_check":"2013-07-21T09:04:25.000-04:00","suppress_retailer_approval":false,"suppress_retailer_approval_reason":null,"ebb_description":null,"slug":"dead-by-midnight","legacy_slug":"dead-by-midnight","us_agency_price":null,"firebrand_title_id":null,"ebb_label":null,"ebb_end_sale_date":null,"ebb_downprice":null,"book_club":null,"best_seller":null,"discovery":"Y","narrator_id":null,"legacy_publishers":[{"publisher_id":1,"publisher_name":"Kensington"}],"legacy_contributors":[{"author_id":1,"contact_id":1,"contact":{"display_name":"Beverly Barton"}}]}]}
```

I keep getting object object.  I'm not sure what I'm doing wrong.

Comment: getting "object object" is usually a sign of trying to convert an object to a string, so maybe you do have the right reference, you're just outputting it incorrectly. Either way, we need to see more code to tell.

Comment: Can you show what you tried ?

Comment: It should be `obj.data[0].legacy_publishers[0].publisher_name` id the entire object is names obj

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`data` has an array property, so does `legacy_publishers` - make sure you specify the array index:

```
data[0].legacy_publishers[0].publisher_name
```